# use cheerio to get a list of attributes

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I want to get `['http://www.1.com', 'http://www.2.com', 'http://www.3.com']` from following string.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const htmlStr = `
<div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://www.1.com"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://www.2.com"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://www.3.com"></a>
  </div>

</div>
`

const $ = cheerio.load(htmlStr)
```

Initially, I thought `$(div.item a)` will return an array of elements. So I tried with :

```
const urls = $('div.item a').map(x => x.attr('href'))
```

It failed.

Seems `$('div.item a')` returns an `object`.

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, cheerio's `map` function takes a callback where the first argument is the current *index*, not element that again must be wrapped in `$(…)`. Next, `map` returns a "jQuery set", not a vanilla JavaScript array. Use `toArray`:

```
$('div.item a').map((i, x) => $(x).attr('href')).toArray()
```

Comment: very informative for me `map returns a "jQuery set"`, thanks! @Li357

Answer (score 4):

figure out another way:

```
$('div.item a').get().map(x => $(x).attr('href'))
```

`get()` retrieve all elements matched.